# Herbicide for shameplant and not grass

Tags: lawn, weed-control, herbicide

My lawn has been overrun by the shameplant (Mimosa Pudica). It is a rather large area. Is there an herbicide that will kill the shameplant and not the grass?

Some pics of the lawn [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXYvV.jpg).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most herbicides for lawn. Mimosa is a dicots, grass are monocots. Often herbicides makes such differences: a lot useful (for lawn, but the contrary, for cultivation).

It is difficult to name herbicides, because names changes from country to country (and also inside a country you have different names for the same herbicide, according trademark and liceses from big (weed) killers).

But go to a shop, and look for herbicides for lawn, you will for sure find many. Some lawn fertilizers also include it, but if you have too many weeds,  you should use herbicides.

BTW do you fertilize your lawn? This could give some strength to grass.

Comment: I live in the Caribbean, specifically Puerto Rico. I've been searching the weed list on the big name herbicides (Roundup, Ortho, Spectracide, etc...) that kill the weeds and not the grass, but none specify mimosas or shameplant. I don't really water nor fertilize my lawn. I just want to get rid of the shameolant, at the moment.

Comment: You do not need an herbicide specific for mimosa. It would be impractical to list all weeds, for e.g. Roundup and large spectrum herbicides. Large spectrum are general (nearly all), monocots (so grass), dicots (so "large leaves", as they write sometime on herbicides), annuals, perennials, mosses. Sometime they have also more specific (but still general, as families). In any case, you should choose an herbicide for weeds in lawns. Mimosa is a "large leave plant" for gardeners (and systematics)

Comment: Is there a specific chemical and percentage I should look out for?